# Random garbled web page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7.5

I have a site hosted on a dedicated server (`2008 R2 IIS7.5`) and every so often I get a garbled web page similar to the ones below.  The entire screen is filled with garbage.   There seems to no pattern to the issue and it happens to others as well.  I could go for hours, maybe days surfing the site without seeing it though.  They are all `.aspx` pages on the site.  Any ideas?

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=utf-8 Content-Encoding: gzip Vary: Accept-Encoding Server:
>   Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Thu, 10 Mar 2011 17:48:59 GMT Content-Length: 9874 ? ????? ?? 
>   `I?%&/m?{ J?J??t? ?` $?@ ????? iG#)?*??eVe]f @????{???{??;?N'????\fd
>   l??J??!??? ?~| ?"~??7N ??O?U????`@??P??????l9??T?L?????????C?7N?????? - snip -
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=utf-8 Content-Encoding: gzip Vary: Accept-Encoding Server:
>   Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Mon, 28 Mar 2011 20:23:42 GMT Content-Length: 10601 ‹ í½ 
>   `I–%&/mÊ{ JõJ×àt¡ €` $Ø @ ìÁˆÍæ’ì iG#)«* ÊeVe]f @Ìí ¼÷Þ{ï½÷Þ{ï½÷º;
>   N'÷ßÿ?\fd löÎJÚÉž!€ªÈ ?~| ?"~ãä7N ÿ®O¿^ämFãiWÛù/Z —Ÿ}tR-[j²ýæz•
>   ”Nå¯Ï>jówí]À?L§ó¬nòö³¢©¶
>   î?ÜÞý(½{ô¸,–oÓ:/?û¨i¯Ë¼™çyûQ:¯óóÏ>ªó¦Z×Ó¼¹;mš»ôWÞŽé· Ò–zQàü÷"Ÿ A˜Öy¾|O
>   - snip-

Answer (score 1):

Without inspecting the server I would not be able to tell you much, because a lot of  times you would just look for idiosyncrasies or differences in configuration.

All I can say - **for what is worth** - is that there seems to be something to do with the `GZIP` (and not the encoding),  considering this is a new feature in IIS. Both cases have `GZIP` turned on. Now it could be that you have turned the feature on but I suggest turning it off for a while to see if it happens again. This could be in fact a bug in IIS.

Comment: I had the same issue (Windows web server 2008 R2, IIS7). I had both dynamic and static compression installed. Uninstalling static did not solve it but uninstalling both did. The error pages were (as far as I can tell) all with AJAX calls returning json involved.